# URL rewriting is not properly configured

Tags: cakephp

While running CakePHP on my system, I am getting the following error:

URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server.    1) Help me configure it 2) I don't / can't use URL rewriting

mod_rewrite is enabled on server.

The thing which look suspicious to me is that the following files in root folder are named incorrectly:

.htaccess is named as _htaccess 
.editorconfig is named as _editorconfig 
.gitignore is named as _editorconfig 
.travis.yml is named as _travi.yml

When I tried to rename these files according to their correct name, it gave 'Internal Server Error'.

Please help me in resolving the error.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you hosting this, locally or on a server?

Comment: did you restart the apache after enabling the mod rewrite, also, pls check  `app/tmp/logs/error.log` file, if there is nothing useful in there then apache's error log should give some insight

Comment: @toby1kenobi I am hosting it locally